# Text selection bind in android 3.1

Tags: android

When you select text in android, a toolbar is opened with COPY & PASTE & WEB SEARCH.
is there a way i can add stuff there via the API somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the context of the text you are selecting?  Is it in an EditText box? Or just highlighted text on a web page?

If it is an EditText, I think the answer is no.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyLongPress(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

This is the **onLongPress** of the EditText, where you can choose to either handle the event yourself or pass it on to be handled internally.  It sounds like you want to be able to modify the way it handles the event internally, which I don't think you can do.  The only way would be to implement your own spinner popup, with all of those options + yours.

Comment: i want to use it everywhere in the android - not just my application. i want to add a button in the text selection in all the platform

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  That would have to be wired into your own custom build of android.